# login echoing not working

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

so my login works but trying to echo the username from the DB wont work the error says 
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/..../public_html/app/views/login/logout.php on line 31"
my code:

```
  <?php  
    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
    //3.1.1 Assigning posted values to variables.
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `loginuser` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    //3.1.2 If the posted values are equal to the database values, then session will be created for the user.
    if ($count == 1){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    }else{
    //3.1.3 If the login credentials doesn't match, he will be shown with an error message.
    echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
    }
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    echo "Hello " . $username . "";
    echo "This is the Members Area";
    echo "<a href='logout'>Logout</a>";
    }else{


    ?>
```

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**

Comment: You're missing your closing bracket for your else statement.

Comment: Missing closing brace for `else{` --- Either add `}` or get rid of it.

Comment: Use => [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `}` for your `else` statement at the end. Or delete it, because it is not in use.

```
}else{
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <?php  
> session_start();
>
> if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
> //3.1.1 Assigning posted values to variables.
> $username = $_POST['username'];
> $password = $_POST['password'];
>
> $query = "SELECT * FROM `loginuser` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
>
> $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
> $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
> //3.1.2 If the posted values are equal to the database values, then session will be created for the user.
> if ($count == 1){
> $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
> }else{
> //3.1.3 If the login credentials doesn't match, he will be shown with an error message.
> echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
> }
> }
>
> if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
> $username = $_SESSION['username'];
> echo "Hello " . $username . "";
> echo "This is the Members Area";
> echo "<a href='logout'>Logout</a>";
> }else{
>     // Do nothing
> }
> ?>
> ```

Or omit the last else completely.